# Mongodb aggregation nested query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

Sorry about the bad title, but here is the problem I'm trying to solve:

I have a couple of collections, including ticket, fields, and fieldOptions that look something like this:

**Ticket**:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    subject: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
    fields: [
        {
            key: "part-number",
            value: "abc123",
        },
        {
            key: "price",
            value: "10",
        },
        {
            key: "officer",
            value: "2",
        },
    ]
}
```

**Fields**:

```
[
    {
        _id: 1,
        created: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        options: [],
        updated: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        active: true,
        displayOrder: 0,
        key: "part-number",
        label: "Part Number",
        required: false,
        type: "text",
    },
    {
        _id: 2,
        created: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        options: [],
        updated: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        active: true,
        displayOrder: 1,
        key: "price",
        label: "Price",
        required: false,
        type: "text",
    },
    {
        _id: 3,
        created: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        options: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        updated: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        active: true,
        displayOrder: 2,
        key: "officer",
        label: "Officer",
        required: false,
        type: "select",
    },
    // THIS WAS ADDED AFTER THE 'TICKET' DOC WAS CREATED, SO IT'S NOT LISTED UNDER 'FIELDS' IN THERE
    {
        _id: 4,
        created: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        options: [],
        updated: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        active: true,
        displayOrder: 1,
        key: "notes",
        label: "Notes",
        required: false,
        type: "text",
    },
]
```

**Field Options**:

```
[
    {
        _id: 1,
        created: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        updated: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        active: true,
        key: "none",
        label: "None",
        displayOrder: 0,
        legacy: false,
    },
    {
        _id: 2,
        created: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        updated: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        active: true,
        key: "picard",
        label: "Picard",
        displayOrder: 1,
        legacy: false,
    },
    {
        _id: 3,
        created: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        updated: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        active: true,
        key: "riker",
        label: "Riker",
        displayOrder: 2,
        legacy: false,
    },
    {
        _id: 4,
        created: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        updated: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        active: true,
        key: "data",
        label: "Data",
        displayOrder: 3,
        legacy: false,
    },
    {
        _id: 5,
        created: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        updated: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
        active: true,
        key: "red-shirt",
        label: "Red Shirt",
        displayOrder: 4,
        legacy: true,
    },
]
```

In my aggregation pipeline, I have the following:

```
[
    { $match: {_id: 2} },
    { $unwind: { path: "$fields", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true } },
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "fields",
                    "let": { "key": "$fields.key" },
                    "as": "fields.def",
                    "pipeline": [
                        { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$key", "$$key"] } } },
                        {
                            "$lookup": {
                                "from": "fieldoptions",
                                "let": { "options": "$options" },
                                "pipeline": [
                                    { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$_id", "$$options"] } } },
                                ],
                                "as": "options"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            { $unwind: { path: "$fields.def", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true } },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$_id",
                    fields: { $push: "$$ROOT.fields" },
                    root: { $mergeObjects: "$$ROOT" },
                }
            },
            {
                $replaceRoot: {
                    newRoot: {
                        $mergeObjects: ["$root", "$$ROOT"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $unset: "root"
            },
            { $project: { fields: '$fields'}} // this is to remove other junk for testing
]
```

Which brings back the following (almost correct) result:

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "fields" : [ 
        {
            "key" : "part-number",
            "value" : "abc123",
            "def" : {
                "_id" : 1,
                "created" : ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
                "options" : [],
                "updated" : ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
                "active" : true,
                "displayOrder" : 0,
                "key" : "part-number",
                "label" : "Part Number",
                "required" : false,
                "type" : "text",
                "__v" : 0
            }
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "price",
            "value" : "10",
            "def" : {
                "_id" : 2,
                "created" : ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
                "options" : [],
                "updated" : ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
                "active" : true,
                "displayOrder" : 1,
                "key" : "price",
                "label" : "Price",
                "required" : false,
                "type" : "text",
                "__v" : 0
            }
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "officer",
            "value" : "2",
            "def" : {
                "_id" : 3,
                "created" : ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
                "options" : [ 
                    {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "created" : ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
                        "updated" : ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
                        "active" : true,
                        "key" : "none",
                        "label" : "None",
                        "displayOrder" : 0,
                        "legacy" : false,
                        "__v" : 0
                    }, 
                    {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "created" : ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
                        "updated" : ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
                        "active" : true,
                        "key" : "picard",
                        "label" : "Picard",
                        "displayOrder" : 1,
                        "legacy" : false,
                        "__v" : 0
                    }, 
                    {
                        "_id" : 3,
                        "created" : ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
                        "updated" : ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
                        "active" : true,
                        "key" : "riker",
                        "label" : "Riker",
                        "displayOrder" : 2,
                        "legacy" : false,
                        "__v" : 0
                    }, 
                    {
                        "_id" : 4,
                        "created" : ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
                        "updated" : ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
                        "active" : true,
                        "key" : "data",
                        "label" : "Data",
                        "displayOrder" : 3,
                        "legacy" : false,
                        "__v" : 0
                    }
                ],
                "updated" : ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
                "active" : true,
                "displayOrder" : 2,
                "key" : "officer",
                "label" : "Officer",
                "required" : false,
                "type" : "select",
                "__v" : 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My issue is that if I add something to the 'fields' collection (let's call it property 'foo'), the existing ticket objects do not have the 'foo' ref, so it does not show up in the ticket object, I would like to somehow (in the aggregation framework) get the list of current fields, and for each look up the corresponding value if it exists, otherwise return with an empty value like so:

**new ticket result**:

```
{
    _id: 2,
    fields: [
        ... //existing fields
        {
            key: "foo", // <-- new fields / fields not listed on the ticket
            value: null,
            def: {
                _id: 1,
                created: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
                options: [],
                updated: ISODate("2020-09-10T20:23:46.382Z"),
                active: true,
                displayOrder: 0,
                key: "foo",
                label: "Foo",
                required: false,
                type: "text",
                __v: 0,
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

How can this be accomplished? Also, is there a better way to do this than what I have? I'm very new to aggregation and still experimenting.

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not.

Answer (score 1):

Its is totally lengthy process to combine both fields, you can follow the steps,

- `$match` your condition
- `$addFields` to add a array of fields `key` in a `keys` array
- `$facet` to generate 2 separate array, one for matched fields and second for unmatched array

  - make array of matched fields in `fields`, pass `keys` array in let and match `$in` query and lookup with `fieldoptions` collection,

    - `$project` to get combine objects with current root keys and value using `$map` and `$reduce`
  - make array of unmatched fields in `other_fields`, pass `keys` array in let and match `$not` and `$in` query means not include and lookup with `fieldoptions` collection

    - `$project` to get combine objects with current root keys and value using `$map` and `$mergeObjects`
- `$project` to concat both arrays in `fields` array using `$concatArrays`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `fields` array
- `$replaceWith` `fields` object replace to root
- `$unwind` deconstruct `fields` array
- `$group` by ticket id and construct array of `fields`

```
db.ticket.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: 1 } },
  { $addFields: { keys: { $map: { input: "$fields", in: "$$this.key" } } } },
  {
    $facet: {
      fields: [
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "fields",
            let: { key: "$keys" },
            as: "_fields",
            pipeline: [
              { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$key", "$$key"] } } },
              {
                $lookup: {
                  from: "fieldoptions",
                  localField: "options",
                  foreignField: "_id",
                  as: "options"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            fields: {
              $map: {
                input: "$fields",
                as: "f",
                in: {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                    "$$f",
                    {
                      def: {
                        $reduce: {
                          input: "$_fields",
                          initialValue: {},
                          in: {
                            $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$f.key", "$$this.key"] }, "$$this", "$$value"]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      other_fields: [
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "fields",
            let: { key: "$keys" },
            as: "_fields",
            pipeline: [
              { $match: { $expr: { $not: { $in: ["$key", "$$key"] } } } },
              {
                $lookup: {
                  from: "fieldoptions",
                  localField: "options",
                  foreignField: "_id",
                  as: "options"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            fields: {
              $map: {
                input: "$_fields",
                as: "f",
                in: {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                    { def: "$$f" },
                    { key: "$$f.key", value: null }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $project: { fields: { $concatArrays: ["$fields", "$other_fields"] } } },
  { $unwind: "$fields" },
  { $replaceWith: "$fields" },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$fields",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      fields: { $push: "$$ROOT.fields" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZNUvl-fA9dG)

---

Your query in question, this is a optimized version of that query [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uEYtu5AqYPm)